# why list comprehension beats zip in transposing matrix

Tags: python, performance, zip, list-comprehension

Recently I'm using python to process some million sized list.

Here I have a list **E**, it has 1,470,000 elements, each element is a list with 2 integers.

E looks like: [[1, 3], [2, 4], [4, 7] ... ]

I want to get the max number of the first column and the second column respectively.

I can get it by using list comprehension

```
m1 = max([e[0] for e in E])
m2 = max([e[1] for e in E])
return (m1, m2)
```

Another method is to use zip:

```
list(map(max, zip(*E)))
```

At the first thought I think the second way should be faster, since the list comprehension is going to build a big list (what's more, for 2 times). But it turns out list comprehension to be extremely fast and the method using zip is around 10 ~ 20 times slower (using cProfile).

I think the zip shouldn't be that slow, (what's more, how could a list comprehension to be that fast?) Can anybody tells me the reason?

I'm using python 3.2

P.S. by using Windows Task Manager, I can't even see any memory trace shows that python ever created a new list. There must be a black magic.

Comment: I don't know if Python requires the elements of a tuple to be evaluated in a particular order, but if it doesn't (and you're on Python 2.x) then I think this is undefined behavior... `e` is the same variable in both list comprehensions.

Comment: If you're dealing with stuff like this - have you considered using numpy...? `>>> a = np.array([ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] ])
>>> a.max(axis=0)
array([5, 6])`

Comment: @Mehrdad Sorry for my confusing sample code. But even I calculate the two max totally separately, it would be still much faster, which I can't understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tested a variety of methods using both Python 2.7.3 and 3.3.0, and I cannot reproduce your results.

The following timings are from Python 2.7.3 (the results from 3.3.0 are similar):

```
In [31]: E = [(random.randrange(0,1000),random.randrange(0,1000)) for _ in range(1470000)]

In [32]: %timeit max([e[0] for e in E]), max([e[1] for e in E])
1 loops, best of 3: 319 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit max(e[0] for e in E), max(e[1] for e in E)
1 loops, best of 3: 343 ms per loop

In [36]: %timeit max(E, key=operator.itemgetter(0)), max(E, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
1 loops, best of 3: 314 ms per loop

In [38]: %timeit list(map(max, zip(*E)))
1 loops, best of 3: 307 ms per loop
```

All the methods I've tested have about the same performance.

If you care about performance, you should consider using NumPy:

```
In [39]: import numpy as np

In [40]: EE = np.array(E)

In [46]: %timeit EE.max(axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.21 ms per loop
```

As you can see, on this data set `numpy.max()` is about 100x faster than any of the pure Python methods I've tried.

Comment: +1 for suggesting numpy. But the time to create the numpy array should also be considered in this case. It may be worth converting the list to an array if there are more calculations following, otherwise if the array isn't a numpy array from the beginning it may be too expensive.

Comment: @mata: You are right. It's clearly not worth converting the `list` to `ndarray` for this computation alone.